# How long is a review queue?

Tags: discussion

When I look at the Badge Process dropdown and look at the progress for on getting the Reviewer badge i.e. Review badges are awarded once per review queue, I wonder how long is a review queue?

[image]

Comment: A queue is not a measure of time. A queue is an entity; there are several different queues (for reviewing suggested edits, late answers, first posts, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you can earn one badge for actions in the "close votes" queue, another for the "low quality posts" queue, one for "reopen votes", etc.

Comment: Ah, so it's action-based, not time-based, correct?

Comment: For folks still confused, [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293927/2909897) helped me understand the wording of this badge.