# Review badges can be awarded once per queue or once per review type?

Tags: support, review-queues, badges

Review badges such as *Custodian*, *Reviewer* and *Steward* can be awarded once per review type or once per review queue?
On [Badge's page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) it said once per review type, but according to this screenshot - once per queue.

[image]

So what is the truth?

**Important notice:** Please, before voting down make sure you understood question. By *review type* was meant *Late answers*, *First posts*, *Triage* etc., and *review queue* is a queue for each type. Example: In *Triage* I reviewed 1000 posts, the queue will start from the beginning, so it will be a different queue. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: Each review queue is of a different type - in other words, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understood how I can figure out the answer, so it is not *review queue*, but *review type* and it is not the same. See attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A different review queue contains a different review type. So both are essentially the same.

So you get the badge for reviewing in different review queues, since the review types are different.